# Crayan Syntax highlighter not showing my xml code properly

Tags: xml, wordpress, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I have installed "Crayon Syntax Highlighter" plugin in my wordpress site.

It is not showing my XML code properly.
This is my actual XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="androidumps.activeandroid" >

<application
android:name=".InitApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<!-- AA_DB_NAME points your database name -->
<meta-data
android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
android:value="rootdatabase.db" />
<!-- AA_DB_VERSION points your database version -->
<meta-data
android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
android:value="1" />
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When i see it in my website, It is looking like this,
[image]

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try asking on their github page: https://github.com/aramk/crayon-syntax-highlighter/issues

Answer (score 3):

Just checkmark **'Decode HTML entities in code'** in *Crayon Syntax Highlighter Settings*, and you are good to go.

Comment: I had to *uncheck* this option to correct the issue.